# can't open project in Android Eclips workspace?

Tags: android, eclipse

If I copy the code to the workspace and try to open it, it shows invalid project description.

The  answers in stack overflow says to copy it to another location and open. but i don't want my projects to be in different places. is there any other way in which i can open the projects in the workspace?

Comment: Well, move it to another location. Then create a new project from existing source, choose the root folder of the project and tick

"copy project into workspace". Now you have imported it AND your code in the workspace

Comment: Are you trying to save two same projects in the workspace?

Comment: @Musterknabe it works. But i that the only way?

Comment: @Brontok no. i copied a library project to workspace folder. but i cant open it in eclipse. seems that i have to copy it somewhere else and ask eclipse to copy code to workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the answer myself. 
selecting the whole workspace folder instead of the needed project folder to import and select only the needed project solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use following answer,,

1) create new android application project,

2) give Project Name,Package Name etc on first screen,, Click next,,,-->uncheck Create custom Launcher Icon and Create Activity..-->Finish

3) right click on created project--->Import--->General--->FileSystem--->Next

4) check src folder,res folder and Manifest file click finish

5)project will get imported into eclipse